# Why does the compiler allocate excess memory when reading a text file?

Tags: c, io, text-files

I'm trying to read a text file into a dynamic string (`char *` array).

- Initially, I get the length of the file using `fileLength = ftell(textFile);` and the debugger reports the `fileLength = 214`. I've manually checked the file length on *VSCode*: opened file in editor and selected all chars using `<ctrl+a>`; number of selected chars is reported as 214 again.
- However, when debugger hits the `if` block in the `while` loop I realized that, the pointer `tmp` is only 202 chars (202 bytes) away from `src` (the head of the string).
- Strangely, the difference (214 - 202 = 12) corresponds to the number of lines in the text file. That coincidence made me think that; when calculating the length (number of chars), compiler considers the `eol` as `\r\n` but when actually reading the chars, `eol` is recognized as `\n` (I'm on *Windows*).

Can someone elaborate whether I am right or wrong in my suspicion?

```
char *FileTextRead(const char *fileName) {
    char c = 0;
    char *src = NULL;
    char *tmp = NULL;
    size_t head = 0L;
    size_t fileLength = 0L;
    FILE *textFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (textFile == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file : %s\n", fileName);
    }
    else {
        // save head position of file
        head = ftell(textFile);

        // go to end of file to get number of chars
        fseek(textFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
        fileLength = ftell(textFile);

        // rewind file to the head
        fseek(textFile, head, SEEK_SET);

        src = malloc((fileLength + 1) * sizeof(char));

        if (src == NULL) {
            printf("failed to allocate memory...\n");
        }
        else {
            tmp = src;

            while (TRUE) {
                c = getc(textFile);

                if (feof(textFile)) {
                    *tmp = '\0';
                    break;
                }

                *tmp = c;
                tmp++;
            }
        }

        fclose(textFile);
    }

    return src;
}
```

Comment: This is an extraordinarily inefficient way to read data. Consider using [`fread()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and do it in larger chunks, like 16KB or more. Each kernel call is extremely painful from the perspective of your program, so doing one character at a time is likely a thousand times slower than reading in 1KB chunks.

Comment: @tadman : Just another question if you don't mind: When using `fread`, will the line `fread(src, sizeof(char), fileLength, textFile);` guarantee that the program would read all the text file at once? I mean, is there **buffer** limit to be considered? (when I say **buffer** limit, I don't mean my `malloc`ed char array but the `io` buffer on the operating systems side).

Comment: That should be `fread(src, fileLength, fileLength, textFile)` if, and only if your buffer is big enough to contain the whole file. In your version you read just `sizeof(char)` or one byte. Remember a lot can happen between your `ftell` call and the actual read, you may end up working on a file that's actively being appended to, so you may not read all the bytes in the file. Check the return value to see how many bytes were read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to [`fopen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) in *binary mode* if that's important, which it can be on some platforms:

```
FILE *textFile = fopen(fileName, "rb");
```

Comment: Took your word (in you prev. comment, now deleted), I've tested another file with 8079 chars & 328 lines; got the same result: when program execution hits inside the `if` block, pointer `tmp` is only 7752 chars away from pointer `src`. Then, tested using `fopen(fileName, "rb")` and it's OK now.

Comment: One other thing to watch out for on Windows is UTF-16 files. Many programs create them as a matter of fact and C can't really deal without conversion.